# keycloak java.lang.RuntimeException: Must set 'realm' in config

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

Trying to integrate Keycloak into Spring Boot App but get the following error:

```
Must set 'realm' in config
```

I have the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter'
}

dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom 'org.keycloak.bom:keycloak-adapter-bom:13.0.0'
}
}
```

This is my Security Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class KeycloakSecurityConfiguration extends
    KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll();
    http.csrf().disable();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();

    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
            new SimpleAuthorityMapper()
    );

    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy(){
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy( new SessionRegistryImpl());
}

@Bean
public KeycloakConfigResolver KeyCloakConfigResolver(){
    return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
}

}
```

And this is my Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Hello")
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/helloWorld", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getHello() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World");
}
}
```

This is my application.yml:

```
server:
 port: 8081
keycloak:
 realm: SpringBootHelloKeycloak
 auth-server-url: http://localhost:8180/auth
 ssl-required: external
 resource: login-app
 credentials:
   secret: c0a68675-8f16-4a13-83dd-6d2111d74ee6
 use-resource-role-mappings: true
 bearer-only: true
```

When i'm trying to request like this:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:8081/Hello/helloWorld'
```

The App throws the following error:

```
2021-05-23 21:41:43.620 ERROR 40908 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing /Hello/helloWorld
java.lang.RuntimeException: Must set 'realm' in config
at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:57) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.0.jar:13.0.0]
at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:202) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.0.jar:13.0.0]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.resolve(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.java:41) ~[keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-core-13.0.0.jar:13.0.0]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.resolve(KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.java:40) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-13.0.0.jar:13.0.0]
at org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext.resolveDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContext.java:89) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.0.jar:13.0.0]
at org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.preflightCors(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:100) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.0.jar:13.0.0]
at org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:75) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-13.0.0.jar:13.0.0]
at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:177) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-13.0.0.jar:13.0.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]

2021-05-23 21:41:43.627  INFO 40908 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-05-23 21:41:43.627  INFO 40908 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-05-23 21:41:43.628  INFO 40908 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2021-05-23 21:41:43.637 ERROR 40908 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
```

Does someone know what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Do you have in your configuration keycloak.realm= ?

Comment: I'm using application.yml and I have keycloak:
 realm: SpringBootHelloKeycloak

Comment: Sorry I miss that part

Comment: Did you try using configuration with properties to see if made any difference?

Comment: same error, but in application.properties IntlliJ gives me the warning "Unused Property" for every entry. Unless I have # suppress inspection "UnusedProperty"

Comment: Just solved it, in the application.yml the keycloak parameter was indented to far by one space. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: "Hate" does yaml because of that, nice that you have solved it :)